# Is sailsJs efficient in saving bulk data with 50k rows

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js, bulk

Is there an issue with regards to SailsJs' ORM in saving more or less **50k rows**? Do I have to extend the response timeout? The database being used is Mysql btw.